# Regarding age of a player in the the ICC Under 19 World Cup

Tags: cricket, icc

What is the minimum age for a player to play the ICC Under 19 World Cup? I have tried but cannot know it from any one.

Answer (score 5):

In [this](http://www.africacricket.org/pdf%27s/32_qualification_rules_u19_age_determination_policy.pdf) document, there is no where mentioned minimum age limitation so it can be smoothly assumed that there is no minimum age limit

Answer (score -1):

There is no limit for minimum age. If a young player is good enough he can make into the team.

Comment: Could you please add a reference for this?

Comment: I don't think he'll find a reference - under 19 means under 19. By definition there is no minimum.

Comment: yes, there is no minimum, as the rule for age during 2014 u19 WC was the player should be born on or after september 1, 1994. "NO" mentioning of before.  Afghanistan’s Shahidullah became that edition’s youngest player at an age of 15.6 years.